# Importing JSON as point layer into QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, import, json, qgsvectorlayer

I have a JSON file created by an API request. I wish to import this file directly into QGIS (ideally with a model or a Python script) so that with one click the data are on the project.

I have tried several ways, but I'm not able to import it directly on QGIS, the maximum was writing a python script OUTSIDE QGIS, which was not readable by PyQGIS. Any hints?

The data look like this:

```
[
    {"dd":1669622400,"df":1671202800,"r":"A","p":"Sw","t":"2","c":"1","lar":"3.75","s":"-1","lon":9.41564,"lat":47.4403,"code":"tp","txt":""},
    {"dd":1637726400,"df":1698638400,"r":"A","p":"Sw","t":"2","c":"1","lar":"4.45","s":"-1","lon":9.3903,"lat":47.43345,"code":"tp","txt":""},
    {"dd":1682539200,"df":1682564400,"r":"A","p":"Sw","t":"2","c":"401","lar":"3.5","s":"-1","lon":9.36115,"lat":47.42871,"code":"cl","txt":""}
]
```

and has more than 600 input.

`"dd","df","r","p","t","c","lar","s","lon","lat","code"` and `"txt"` are the "titles" of the different columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this PyQGIS solution.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from json import load
from os.path import normpath
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import edit, QgsProject, QgsField, QgsPointXY, QgsFeature, QgsVectorLayer

# specifying a path to the JSON file
path_to_json = normpath("C:/Users/taras/example.json")

# reading JSON file
with open(path_to_json, "r") as jsonFile:
    data = load(jsonFile)

# preparing an empty point layer for the output
output_crs = "epsg:4326"
point_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"Point?crs={output_crs}", "temp", "memory")

# nesting fields into the output layer
data_provider = point_layer.dataProvider()
data_provider.addAttributes([
    QgsField('dd', QVariant.Int),
    QgsField('df', QVariant.Int),
    QgsField('r', QVariant.String),
    QgsField('p', QVariant.String),
    QgsField('t', QVariant.Int),
    QgsField('c', QVariant.Int),
    QgsField('lar', QVariant.Double),
    QgsField('s', QVariant.Int),
    QgsField('code', QVariant.String),
    QgsField('txt', QVariant.String)
    ])
point_layer.updateFields()

# editing point layer
with edit(point_layer):
    # looping over each record in the input data
    for record in data:
        feat = QgsFeature(point_layer.fields()) # providing fields for features
        feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(record['lon'], record['lat']))) # setting features geometries
        del record['lat'] # deleting not needed field
        del record['lon'] # deleting not needed field
        feat.setAttributes(list(record.values())) # filling features with attributes
        data_provider.addFeatures([feat]) # adding features
point_layer.updateExtents()

# adding the point layer to map canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer)
```

*Input:*

```
[
{"dd":1669622400,"df":1671202800,"r":"A","p":"Sw","t":"2","c":"1","lar":"3.75","s":"-1","lon":9.41564,"lat":47.4403,"code":"tp","txt":""},
{"dd":1637726400,"df":1698638400,"r":"A","p":"Sw","t":"2","c":"1","lar":"4.45","s":"-1","lon":9.3903,"lat":47.43345,"code":"tp","txt":""},
{"dd":1682539200,"df":1682564400,"r":"A","p":"Sw","t":"2","c":"401","lar":"3.5","s":"-1","lon":9.36115,"lat":47.42871,"code":"cl","txt":""}
]
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like this:

*Output:*
[image: result]

Comment: To run in the python editor console is incredible amazing, but i can still not load as a script in the instrument. "NameError: name 'edit' is not defined". Do you have more ideas?

Comment: Website doesn't allow me to upload a screenshot, however, this is the complete message: "Processing: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 228, in runAlgorithm exec(self.editor.text(), _locals) File "", line 29, in NameError: name 'edit' is not defined "

Comment: I add the picture in the question

Comment: `from qgis.core import edit` is missing

Comment: for who care was also missing "from qgsi.core import QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY" many thanks to Taras and bugmenot123